# Class property Can't ref In myFunction，Is any Better practice

Tags: c#

I have some XML Data need to Convert Item Just Like

---

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int? Age{get;set;} 
}
```

---

And I Write Convert Function To Use In My Project (not In same .cs)

---

```
public static bool GetString(XmlNode node,string ID,ref string Result)
{
    bool bl = false;
    string Value;
    if (GetXMLData(node,ID,out Value) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) )
        {
          bl = true;
          Result = Value;
        }
    else
        {
          bl = false;
         }
        return bl;
}
public static bool GetInt(XmlNode node, string ID, ref int? Result)
{
    bool bl = false;
    string Value;
    if (GetXMLData(node, ID, out Value) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
        {
            bl = true;
             Result = Int32.Parse(Value);
        }
    else
        {
            bl = false;
        }
    return bl;
}
```

---

### I Want Use Function Like

```
XMLNode Node = XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode("Data");
MyItem item = new MyItem();

GetString(Node,"Name",ref item.Name);
GetString(Node,"Age",ref item.Age);
```

---

But compiler Show Error...

```
A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter
```

Is any Better practice can tell me?

Thank

---

Thank Everyone !! The problem has been solved !!
I take this suggest and it really help me

```
GetString(node, "fieldValue", x => Item.sub = x);
```

And I want To share my condition
My Teacher Let Me Lead a small team to Creat Web
And we use XML to Post Data And INSERT DataBase
And Cols need to Distinguish NULL and String.Empty

some teammate Write this Code To Read XML to Item

```
Item.Name = node.Attributes["Name"].value;
```

some teammate is

```
if(node.Attributes["Name"] != null)
{
   Item.Name = node.Attributes["Name"].value;
}
```

this two Code one will cause nullreferenceexception one will insert String.Empty To DataBase，But I want Insert null col data...
So I need Write Function let Teammate to use prevent any exception...

Thank EveryOne Suggest，I'm First Time Use Stackoverflow，and i get powerfull suggest!!，Thank Again!!

Comment: What error do you get? Always include the exact error messages. They aren’t there just for fun, they explain what’s wrong.

Comment: Sorry，I Edit My Post  and Write Error Message

Comment: You never read the value `Result` inside either function, you should be using `out` instead of `ref`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating thee two helper methods:

```
public static bool GetString(XmlNode node, string ID, Action<string> action)
{
    string result = null;
    bool bl = GetString(node, ID, ref result);
    if (bl)
    {
        action(result);
    }
    return bl;
}

public static bool GetInt(XmlNode node, string ID, Action<int?> action)
{
    int? result = null;
    bool bl = GetInt(node, ID, ref result);
    if (bl)
    {
        action(result);
    }
    return bl;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
GetString(Node, "Name", x => item.Name = x);
GetInt(Node, "Age", x => item.Age = x);
```

Comment: I Will Try this Suggest ，Thank A Lot

Comment: Thiank Your Suggest !! It's Real Help Me!!，

Answer (score 0):

Use variable, instead of property

```
XmlNode Node = XMLDocument.SelectSingleNode("Data");
            MyItem item = new MyItem();
            string name = item.name;
            string age = item.Age;
            GetString(Node, "Name", ref name);
            GetString(Node, "Age", ref age);
```

> When a formal parameter is a reference parameter, the corresponding
>   argument in a method invocation must consist of the keyword ref
>   followed by a variable-reference (section 5.3.3) of the same type as
>   the formal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like you're using the `bool` that gets returned, I would suggest changing the return type to whatever type you are trying to get and remove that type as a parameter. For example, change

`public static bool GetString(XmlNode node,string ID,ref string Result)`

to

`public static string GetString(XmlNode node, string ID)`

and return the parsed result instead of a bool.

Comment: Thank your suggest，return value is bool is use for some situation is var if null，need to change default value and different web page have different default value，so，return bool is necessary